# How can one stop the execution of a foreign method in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to, and if so how can I, stop the execution of a method that exists in a foreign dependency with Java perhaps by using something such as AoP i.e, AspectJ?

Take this scenario for example:

Foreign code:

```
class SomeForeignClass {
  private Entity entity;

  public void anApiMethod(String aString) {
    entity.doSomethingWith(aString);
  } 
}
```

If `anApiMethod` were called, I would want my application to be able to know about its invocation through some sort of listener (this is where I thought AoP might come in handy) and based on some condition either allow it to continue executing or take over control (perhaps for example, save aString for later execution.)

It is currently my understanding that to get close to something like this I would need to fork the existing dependency, make my own changes, and then depend on my own fork. Is this true?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Robert The framework I use calls a specific method when an event happens. I want that method not to execute based on a condition I set in my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not necessarily true.  It depends on who creates instances of `SomeForeignClass`.   If you create them, or you can reinject replacements for them, then you could extend the class and get this new class to act as a wrapper.

```
SomeForeignClass sfc = getXX();
Wrapper w = new Wrapper(sfc);
setXX(w);
```

Where Wrapper is

```
class Wrapper extends SomeForeignClass {
    final SomeForeignClass sfc;

    Wrapper(SomeForeignClass _sfc) {
         sfc = _sfc;
    }

    @Override
    void anApiMethod(String aString) {
        if ( condition() )
             sfc.anApiMethod(aString);
        else
             anAlternateMethod(aString);
    }

    /* ... etc ... */
}
```

If `entity` can be retrieved somehow, it could be a little simpler, as you wouldn’t need to override every public member, only the ones of interest.

```
class Wrapper extends SomeForeignClass {

    Wrapper(SomeForeignClass _sfc) {
        super(_sfc.getEntity() );
    }

    @Override
    void anApiMethod(String aString) {
        if ( condition() )
             super.anApiMethod(aString);
        else
             anAlternateMethod(aString);
    }
}
```

But just because it might be possible to do it this way doesn’t mean you should; it may be simpler to depend on your own fork, at least until the change can be pushed upstream.